# Trouble using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a newbie, so this might be super basic. 
When I run this code

```
Dplot <- qplot(x = diamonds$carat, y = diamonds$price, color = diamonds$color) +
  ggtitle("An A+ plot") +
  xlab("carat") +
  ylab("price") +
  geom_point()

Dplot <- Dplot + facet_wrap(vars(diamonds$clarity))
Dplot
```

I get an error message that says:

> Error in gList(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1, just = 
>       "centre",  : 
>       only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"

I've tried googling, but haven't been able to figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against using `qplot` except in the most basic cases. It teaches bad habits (like using `$`) that should be avoided in `ggplot`.

We can make the switch by passing the data frame `diamonds` to `ggplot()`, and putting the mappings inside `aes()` with just column names, not `diamonds$`. Then the `facet_wrap` works fine as long as we also omit the `diamonds$`:

```
Dplot = ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price, color = color)) +
  ggtitle("An A+ plot") +
  xlab("carat") +
  ylab("price") +
  geom_point()

Dplot + facet_wrap(vars(clarity))

Dplot + facet_wrap(~ clarity) # another option
```

Notice the code is actually shorter because we don't need to type `diamonds$` all the time!

The `vars(clarity)` option works fine, more traditionally you would see formula interface used `~ clarity`. The `vars()` option is new-ish, and will play a little nicer if you are writing a function where the name of a column to facet by is stored in a variable.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!